# Why do I have this error 'video system not initialized'?

Tags: python, pygame

I already checked solutions but they dont work, I have python 3.10. Suddenly pygame isn't working. To use pygame.unit isnt not the solution, although I always use it. Reinstalling doesnt help either.

````
import pygame
import sys
import random
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tower Defense")

# COLORS




clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:

    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.flip()```
````

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution, so easy,

what I did was (if event.type == pygame.quit():)

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            sys.exit()
```

but actually it is (if event.type == pygame.QUIT:)

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```